# where to find the theme icons in Linux Lubuntu LXQt

Tags: linux, desktop-customization, themes, text-cursor

Linux Lubuntu user here. I want to change two theme elements to a particular, custom icon.
Specifically, these two:

[image]

I thought it would be as simple as finding those images in my system and replacing them with my own files.

But I am having a hard time, could you advice on where to locate those, or where should I look for those files? I am not sure if this depends on Ubuntu itself, SDDM, LXQt, etc.

My system:

**lsb_release -a:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

**apt list lxqt-panel**

```
lxqt-panel/jammy,now 1.4.0-0ubuntu2~ppa22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
lxqt-panel/jammy 0.17.1-0ubuntu1 amd64
```